# Extract audio from video using autogen ffmpeg C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, ffmpeg, autogen

Hi I'm using ffmpeg autogen to extract audio from video in Unity, but when I following this code, the file write cannot write, it's 0Kb, so what's issue of this or someone have any examples for extract audio using this library, apologize for my English. This is github of library: 
https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen

```
unsafe void TestExtractAudio()
{

    string inFile = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + strFileName;
    string outFile = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + strFileNameAudio;

    AVOutputFormat* outFormat = null;
    AVFormatContext* inFormatContext = null;
    AVFormatContext* outFormatContext = null;
    AVPacket packet;

    ffmpeg.av_register_all();

    inFormatContext = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();
    outFormatContext = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();

    if (ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(&inFormatContext, inFile, null, null) < 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not open input file.");
    }

    if (ffmpeg.avformat_find_stream_info(inFormatContext, null) < 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to retrieve input stream info.");
    }

    ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFormatContext, null, null, outFile);
    if (outFormatContext == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not create output context");
    }

    outFormat = outFormatContext->oformat;

    AVStream* inStream = inFormatContext->streams[1];
    AVStream* outStream = ffmpeg.avformat_new_stream(outFormatContext, inStream->codec->codec);
    if (outStream == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to allocate output stream.");
    }

    if (ffmpeg.avcodec_copy_context(outStream->codec, inStream->codec) < 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Couldn't copy input stream codec context to output stream codec context");
    }

    outFormatContext->audio_codec_id = AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_MP3;

    int retcode = ffmpeg.avio_open(&outFormatContext->pb, outFile, ffmpeg.AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (retcode < 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Couldn't open output file");
    }

    int returnCode = ffmpeg.avformat_write_header(outFormatContext, null);

    if (returnCode < 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error occurred opening output file.");
    }

    while (true)
    {
        if (ffmpeg.av_read_frame(inFormatContext, &packet) < 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (packet.stream_index == 1)
        {

            inStream = inFormatContext->streams[1];
            outStream = outFormatContext->streams[0];

            // TODO: Replicate log packet functionality to print out what's inside the packet.

            packet.pts = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.pts, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base,
                AVRounding.AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AVRounding.AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
            packet.dts = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.dts, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base,
                AVRounding.AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AVRounding.AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);

            packet.duration = ffmpeg.av_rescale_q(packet.duration, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base);

            int returncode = ffmpeg.av_interleaved_write_frame(outFormatContext, &packet);

        }

        ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(&packet);
    }

    ffmpeg.av_write_trailer(outFormatContext);


    ffmpeg.avformat_close_input(&inFormatContext);

    ffmpeg.avformat_free_context(outFormatContext);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

the value returnCode return less than 0, so someone can fix this, thanks so much for that

Comment: Have you tried to enable ffmpeg logging?

Comment: uhm, that's script through all code was run in Unity3D, maybe something was mistaken?

Comment: I bet you not going to find that many people who are going run your code at all not even in Unity, thus I'm trying to direct you to help to resolve problem by yourself. First thing here is to get the log output as it might be extreme useful - just add in the beginning of your method  https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/blob/master/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example/Program.cs#L23 from line 23 to 36 and inspect the console output or redirect it to debug output.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was used older repo in Unity and don't have that function, and trying with the newest repo, seems it using c# 7, Unity not yet supports it. I'll try again later.

Comment: You can get compiled library from nuget, you don't need to use entire source base. However, when it comes to Unity  the result might unpredictable. So I would recommend to test it first on full pledged .NET.

Comment: Thank you for supporting devoted, I'll wait for the unity update in next year.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
inStream = inFormatContext->streams[1];
outStream = outFormatContext->streams[0];
```

This code:

```
ffmpeg.av_interleaved_write_frame
```

does the following validation

```
static int check_packet(AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt)
{
if (pkt->stream_index < 0 || pkt->stream_index >= s->nb_streams) {
    av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Invalid packet stream index: %d\n"
}
```

you need to change the `packet.stream_index` from 1 to 0 before calling 
`int returncode = ffmpeg.av_interleaved_write_frame(outFormatContext, &packet);`

See:

```
if (type == AVMediaType.AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO){

    inStream = inFormatContext->streams[1];
    outStream = outFormatContext->streams[0];

    // TODO: Replicate log packet functionality to print out what's inside the packet.

    ffmpeg.av_packet_rescale_ts(&packet, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base);

    packet.stream_index = 0;

    int returncode = ffmpeg.av_write_frame(outFormatContext, &packet);

}
```